# Как запустить Int в onCheckedChanged

Tags: android, kotlin, android-on-click

У меня фрагмент `implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как на Котлине написать `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` общий для всех 17ти чекабельных (`CheckBox`) меню item-ов?

```
override fun onCheckedChanged(item: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) {
    if (isChecked) {
        //???
    } else {
        //???
    }
}
```

Потому что я сейчас прописал для каждого item отдельно, вручную запуская для каждого item соответствующую цифру:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_category1 -> {
            item.isChecked = !item.isChecked
            if (item.isChecked) {
                viewModel.addCategory(1)
            } else {
                viewModel.removeCategory(1)
            }
            true
        }
        R.id.action_category2 -> {
            item.isChecked = !item.isChecked
            if (item.isChecked) {
                viewModel.addCategory(2)
            } else {
                viewModel.removeCategory(2)
            }
            true
        }
        // и так для 17 чекабельных меню item-ов.
```

Не пойму как написать `onCheckedChanged` так, чтобы откуда-то запускать туда цифру, и просто вешать на чекабл item слово `this` вместо того чтобы писать вручную. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать мапу id -> category:

```
val mapIdtoCategory = sequenceOf(
    R.id.action_category1,
    R.id.action_category2,
    ...
)
    .withIndex()
    .associateBy({ it.value }, { it.index + 1 })
```

И использовать так:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val category = mapIdtoCategory[item.itemId] ?: return false
    if (item.isChecked) {
        viewModel.addCategory(category)
    } else {
        viewModel.removeCategory(category)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Пишем отдельный классик `MyListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`
2. Создаем его `myListener:MyListener`
3. В каждом чекабл пишем `item.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myListener)`
4. профит